# Extend template (phtml) and add item in magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, magento-2.0

a question:

How to add an item using a template (phtml) in magento 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add a new item to the customer navigation using layout.xml

Create /app/code/CompanyName/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="link-unique-name-here">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">controller/actionhere</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Link Name Here</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```